# Access control to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, authorization, access-control

I've been told that Oracle database has some utilities to make dynamic data filtering and dynamic data maskering. Since I need this kind of access but I've never used Oracle, I ask if someone can confirm that such utilities exist in Oracle in order to understand if it worth to start using it for my purpose.

Comment: I think you can use [views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11775)

Comment: [Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html); [Transparent Sensitive Data Protection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/using-transparent-sensitive-data-protection.html)

Comment: Depending on your needs, also see [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPSG/GUID-72D524FF-5A86-495A-9D12-14CB13819D42.htm#GUID-14A8D6C6-629B-46C5-86A9-2AED3A46E64D) comparing the features of VPD, Label Security, and Data Redaction.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is dynamic data filtering and dynamic data masking.

There are three ways you can achieve this:

- Oracle's native capability is called Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD)
- Alternatively you can use 3rd party software e.g.

  - Informatica DDM
  - Axiomatics Data Access Filter MD (which is where I work)